# When does wp-cron fire?

Tags: wp-cron

Where in the WP load order does wp-cron fire?  I cannot seem to find this information, and I need to know if I need hook into specific other actions, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum!

By default, wp-cron runs every time an HTTP request is made to a Wordpress site. For this reason, really popular websites have found it necessary to disable the default wp-cron functionality and replace it with a real cron job.

There are several articles available on how to do this.  Using the phrase "Replace wp-cron with real cron" resulted in several hundred examples. [This one](https://docs.wpwebelite.com/replace-wordPress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job/) is fairly generic, but you can probably find one that matches your current host almost exactly.

**ADDED FOR CLARITY:** [WP-CRON is executed as an asynchronous process](http://qnimate.com/how-wordpress-executes-async-cron-without-effecting-page-load-time/). Therefore, you will not be able to "hook into" it in the same way as other filters or actions.  It serves no purpose to understand "when it fires", as it could already be running when a user makes any given HTTP request.

If you need to "hook into it", you should probably view one or more articles on "[scheduling a wordpress cron](https://www.google.com/search?q=scheduling%20a%20wordpress%20cron&oq=scheduling%20a%20wordpress%20cron&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.814j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)".  In particular, I found this [WP Beginner article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-view-and-control-wordpress-cron-jobs/) to be very clear and helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: Right, I understand that it runs for every page load, but when?  Is it before init, after wp.  I would presume after plugins loaded.  During the page load, when is cron fired?  I have nearly 5 years of wp development in my belt, I have yet to actually need to ask a question, as most questions have already been asked.  This particular issue seems to be one that I cannot find an answer, as everyone seems to repeat the same answer as you have provided.

Comment: Since the wp-cron process runs [asynchronously](http://qnimate.com/how-wordpress-executes-async-cron-without-effecting-page-load-time/), you won't find the answer you are looking for.  That's why I provided the second link to "scheduling a wordpress cron". They proper way to "hook into" a cron is to write your own function and "schedule" its execution with wp-cron.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the wp-cron.php, which honestly I should have done in the first place, the file calls wp-load.php, then does all the cron stuff.  So to answer my question the cron hooks are fired after basically every other hook in the WP stack.  Everything is loaded, and in place by the time my cron code runs.